# as.vector() fails on data.table object

Tags: r, vector, data.table

I need to extract a column from a data.table in the form of a vector. I understand that `$` works and `[]` doesn't. Nevertheless, `as.vector()` fails on a data.table object *of a single dimension*.

```
    library(data.table)
    dt <- iris
    setDT(dt)
    oneCol1 <- dt$Sepal.Length[1:100] # produces a vector of 100 elements, fine
    oneCol2 <- dt[1:100,1] # produces a DT 100 rows by 1 column. I understand limitation.
    v <- as.vector(oneCol2) 
    is.vector(v) # FALSE
```

The documentation says `as.vector()`"attempts to coerce ... x, an R object." Nothing happens, though. `v` remains a DT object.

Sure, I can can use the first method, but I wonder why `as.vector()` doesn't work.

Comment: You are basically telling R to convert a data table / data frame into a vector. how is that supposed to work and what is wrong with just doing `v <- as.vector(oneCol2$Sepal.Length)`?

Comment: you need `unlist`

Comment: "I need to extract a column" -- `dt[[1]][1:100]`? You can also type `vignette("datatable-faq")` and read the first answer. (I'd suggest reading the whole thing.)

Answer (score 1):

Data frames are lists. Even if you select one row of a data, it's still considered as a  list.

use unlist instead :

```
 library(data.table)
dt <- iris
setDT(dt)
oneCol1 <- dt$Sepal.Length[1:100] # produces a vector of 100 elements, fine
oneCol2 <- dt[1:100,1] # produces a DT 100 rows by 1 column. I understand limitation.
t<-unlist(oneCol2)
is.vector(t) # true
```